# .net 4.5.2 and ssl 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https

I have a web application which is compiled with .net 4.5.2. Web application access a https service from the server side controller. The application stops working if I disable SSL 3.0 with the following error:

> The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

I came to know from .net 4.6 SSL 3.0 dependency is removed. I tried to install .net 4.7.2 in the server. But still the issue persists.

Do I need to re-compile the application again targetting .net 4.7.2? Is there any way to force the application to make use of TLS 1.2 instead of SSL 3.0?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what is "client" and what is "server" in this question. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue sometimes ago in which we are downloading a file from the controller which is throwing this error.

For that error:

> The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.

and the question:

> Is there any way to force the application to make use of TLS 1.2 instead of SSL 3.0?

You can force your application to use TLS 1.2 by using the following line.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But I think .NET 4.6 is by default uses TLS 1.2.

For more details inspect your requests in the Wireshark which will give the exact version of TLS that is being used by the application.